# Abriviated I18n months coming back blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Somehow, my abbreviated months are coming back blank.

```
Failure:
MessageDecoratorTest#test_it_will_show_date_without_year_if_it's_same_year [/opt/vanadium-web/test/decorators/message_decorator_test.rb:27]:
For locale fr, expected 9 mai, got 9 .
Expected: "9 mai"
  Actual: "9 "
```

My I18 `fr.yml` file is like this:

```
 314   date:
 315     abbr_month_names:
 316   
 317       Jan: janv
 318       Feb: févr.
 319       Mar: mars
 320       Apr: avril
 321       May: mai
 322       Jun: juin
 323       Jul: juill.
 324       Aug: août
 325       Sep: sept.
 326       Oct: oct.
 327       Nov: nov.
 328       Dec: déc.
```

Answer (score 0):

abbr_month_names needed to be structured this way in the `fr.yml` locale file

```
315     abbr_month_names: [~, janv, févr., mars, avril, mai, mai, juill., août, sept., oct., nov., déc.]
```